# useSubscription hook slows down performance

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks, graphql, apollo

```
const { data: result } = useSubscription(
    query,
    {
      id:'abc',
    },
    check === true
);
```

The use of useSubscription(a hook) slows down rendering after a graphQl query is executed. What is the best alternative?

Comment: If it executes a GraphQL query then you'd ideally want to show a loader while the results are being loaded. It would be useful to know where that hook is coming from and what it does though (and how it does it)

Comment: I am already showing the indicator until the data loads, but it takes much time. Needed a check for performance. 'useSubscription' is a graphQl hook that takes input as query along with any other objects as params and returns data list. Reference [link]https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usesubscription

Comment: Well you need to go through a process of elimination for performance problems. (a) make the simplest query you can like get a single field of a single object using `useSubscription` is that still slow? (b) how much of the time taken is the query time and how much is transfer time from db to client?